# Intuition and slick proof that distributions are special cases of hyperfunctions?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am looking for some slick or simple proof that distributions are a special case of hyperfunctions. Furthermore, what is the intuition behind this fact? Why should one think of hyperfunctions as 'distributions of infinite order' as wikipedia says?

I have *not* studied hyperfunctions, so I only think of them naively as the difference of two holomorphic functions (in one variable) on the real line.

[*By the way, I think making a `hyperfunctions` tag may be worth considering*.]

Comment: Try looking in this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=pcSumZ4aPX0C&lpg=PA211&ots=jKoeXr5duQ&dq=sato%20hyperfunction&hl=it&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false pag.64

Comment: (unfortunately that page is not in the preview)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks for the reference. That books only treats the single-variable case. Also, I can't seem to get any intuition out of it.

Comment: See the first volume of Hormander's book "The Analysis of Linear Differential Operators", section 9.1.